# Align label on yaxis in stacked plots

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, axis-labels

I have plotted a stacked image using jupyter. The plot comes out fine but the label on the y axis i'm not able to align to the center. [image]

The MWE is given below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import pylab 
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

def fit_data():

    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(15,15))
    ax1= fig.add_subplot(511,)
    ax1.scatter(data4['MJD'], data4['Favg'],  marker='o', color='red', s=15)
    ax1.errorbar(data4['MJD'], data4['Favg'], data4['Flux-err'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='red', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)
    ax1.set_title('NGC 4151 - Year - 1993', size = 18)

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(512, sharex=ax1 )
    ax2.scatter(data5['MJD'], data5['Favg'],  marker='o', color='blue', s=15)
    ax2.errorbar(data5['MJD'], data5['Favg'], data5['Flux-err'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='blue', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(513, sharex=ax1 )
    ax3.scatter(data6['MJD'], data6['Favg'],  marker='o', color='green', s=15)
    ax3.errorbar(data6['MJD'], data6['Favg'], data6['Flux-err'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='green', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(514, sharex=ax1 )
    ax4.scatter(data7['MJD'], data7['Favg'],  marker='o', color='orange', s=15)
    ax4.errorbar(data7['MJD'], data7['Favg'], data7['Flux-err'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='orange', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(515, sharex=ax1 )
    ax5.scatter(data8['MJD'], data8['Favg'],  marker='o', color='sienna', s=15)
    ax5.errorbar(data8['MJD'], data8['Favg'], data8['Flux-err'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='sienna', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False) # hide labels
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0) # remove vertical space between subplots

    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='o', markersize=5, label='NGC 4151 - 1325 $\AA$')
    ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', marker='o', markersize=5, label='NGC 4151 - 1425 $\AA$')
    ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='green', marker='o', markersize=5, label='NGC 4151 - 1655 $\AA$')
    ax3.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='orange', marker='o', markersize=5, label='NGC 4151 - 2475 $\AA$')
    ax4.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='sienna', marker='o', markersize=5, label='NGC 4151 - 2725 $\AA$')
    ax5.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])


    plt.xlabel('MJD $=$ 2985000 $-$ JD', ha='center',size=10)
    plt.ylabel('Continuum Flux (E$-$14 erg s$^{-1}$ cm$^{-2}$ $\AA^{-1}$)',ha = 'left', va= 'bottom', size=10)


    plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='minor',length=5,width=2,labelsize=18)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',length=8,width=2,labelsize=18)
    plt.tick_params(direction='out', length=8, width=3)
    plt.tick_params(labelsize=7.5)


    plt.savefig("1993.jpeg")
    fig.set_size_inches(w=13,h=10)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


fit_data()
```

If I increase the font size, the y label overlaps the y axis ticks. Also the bottom of the staked image has bold ticks which is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the `pyplot` and the OO API, which always causes problems. See [here in the doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html?highlight=object%20oriented#the-pyplot-api) for a succinct explanation.

You are doing many necessary things in your code (such as creating a 15x15 figure, then resizing it to 13x10), and you are explicitely requesting bold ticks with your `plt.tick_params()` calls, when you say you don't want them...

To center the ylabel, I've substituted `plt.ylabel()` with `fig.text()` which allows you to place the text in figure coordinates, so using a `y=0.5` ensures that the text is in the middle of the figure. You need to adjust the x position so that it does not interfere with your yticks though.

Here is a simplified code:

```
fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(13,10))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(511)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(512, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(513, sharex=ax1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(514, sharex=ax1)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(515, sharex=ax1)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

for ax in [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]:
    ax.tick_params('x', bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

ax1.set_title('NGC 4151 - Year - 1993', size = 18)
ax5.set_xlabel('MJD $=$ 2985000 $-$ JD', size=10)
fig.text(0.075,0.5,'Continuum Flux (E$-$14 erg s$^{-1}$ cm$^{-2}$ $\AA^{-1}$)', ha='center', va='center', size=10, rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]